# Circular imports again

Tags: python, python-3.x, circular-dependency

I'm having a module-structure in python3.8 like this:

```
module
|- __init__.py
|- foo.py
|- bar.py
```

with

```py
# init.py
from .foo import Foo
from .bar import Bar
__all__ = ['Foo', 'Bar', ]
```

I now want to implement a multiplication `foo * bar`. So I'm writing:

```py
# foo.py
from .bar import Bar

class Foo:
  def __init__(self):
    self.value = 5

  def __mul__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Bar): raise ValueError('')
    return self.value * other.number
```

and

```py
# bar.py

from .foo import Foo

class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    self.number = 2

  def __mul__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, Foo): raise ValueError('')
    return other * self
```

This unfortunately doesn't work as expected. Is there a way for type-checking in this case? I know I could import Foo inside of `Bar.__mul__` – but that seems rather untidy to me.

Comment: Instead of checking if the `other` is of type X, you may want to check if the `other` has the attribute you want ? For instance, `if not hasattr(other, "value"): raise` ?

Comment: That's a nice idea! In my specific case the attributes and what get's multiplicated is a bit more complicated, but it would be a "hacky" way to solve the problem. Maybe there's an even better idea though?

Comment: Since these classes seem so tightly coupled, is there a reason they need to live in separate modules?

Comment: @Dunes: The reason is only that I'd like to keep my files tidy with one class per file. So if there is a neat way to combine them, I'd be glad to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping units of logic separated into separate packages and modules can be useful, but to insist that a file only contain one class is verging on dogmatic. Unless these classes are huge, the best solution is to stick them in the same module. Given you're having to resort to various tricks to avoid circular imports, is that really worth being able to keep once class per file?

There are a number of things you can do.

1. Only import the module and not the class (`from module import foo`), and refer to class via the module (eg. `isinstance(obj, foo.Foo)`)
2. Use the "seek forgiveness, not permission" mantra of Python. Assume the user of your classes is using them correctly and that the relevant attributes are present on the operands. If you want more informative error messages then you can wrap attribute fetches in `try: except AttributeError:` statements, which can raise your preferred error. You *must* make sure to put the bare minimum of logic in such try/except blocks. eg. `other_value = other.value`, and then use the `other_value` name outside of the try/except block. This will stop your try/except block hiding possible bugs in your program.
3. Only get one class to implement `__mul__`, this class can then also implement `__rmul__` to make up for the lack of `__mul__` on the other class. This allows all the instance checking to be done in just one of the classes rather than both.

`str` and `int` are examples of where the standard library uses `__rmul__` to compute a result (eg. for `2 * 'a'`). That is, when given `2 * 'a'`, the interpreter first tries `int.__mul__(2, 'a')`. However, this *returns* `NotImplemented`. As a result, the interpreter will then try `str.__rmul__('a', 2)` instead (which returns `'aa'`). You only get his behaviour though when the normal operator function returns `NotImplemented`. If there is an exception then this exception is propagated rather than trying `__rmul__`. When implementing the `r` variant of an operator, you should be mindful that that `self` will be the *right* operand in the expression, and that sometimes this might change how you want to compute the result (eg. `3 - 1 != 1 - 3`).

Example for point 3.

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

class Y:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def _mul(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, X):
            return NotImplemented
        return Y(self.val * x.val)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self._mul(other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self._mul(other)


y = Y(2) * X(3)  # using mul
assert isinstance(y, Y)
assert y.val == 6
assert isinstance(X(3) * Y(2), Y) # using rmul
```

Comment: I didn't know about `__rmul__` and it's precisely what I was searching for, thanks a lot! As I'm currently programming a medium sized library I want to stick to best practice as to keep the code maintainable (but that's maybe because I'm having mainly experience on Java). I'm checking values and throwing exceptions on wrong instances on purpose to avoid typos that happen quickly in my instance. That way I'm at least catching obvious errors.

Answer (score 1):

Import Foo when you need it:

```py
# bar.py

class Bar:
  def __init__(self):
    self.number = 2

  def __mul__(self, other):
    from .foo import Foo
    if not isinstance(other, Foo): raise ValueError('')
    return other * self
```

Bar in this case is already known so there's no more issue

**start of edit**

OK, a little more hacky, but you could define the `__mul__` function outside of the classes:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, value=10):
        self.value = value

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value=5):
        self.value = value

#    def __mul__(self, other):
#        return self.value * other.value

def mul_func(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Bar):
        return self.value * other.value
    raise ValueError('')


Foo.__mul__ = mul_func

a = Foo(5)
b = Bar(10)
c = Foo(20)

a*b
a*c   # value error
```

**end of edit**

Comment: I already thought about that. As stated: "I know I could import Foo inside of `Bar.__mul__` – but that seems rather untidy to me." I somehow have the feeling it should definitely be imported at the top of the file.

Comment: I updated my answer with a second approach... you could assign the function dynamically to the class

Comment: Well that would solve the problem. Seems still hacky but could actually really work. Nice idea!

Answer (score 1):

I would have 2 solutions, either use a workaround with a baseclass, or use something else than the `type` to know you're doing it right.

Edit : I would be curious as to what's the original problem. Since all of this seems hacky to me, or maybe I'm just not seeing the problem in the good way. If we use the `mybase.py` solution, why not just use a single file for the original `foo.py` and `bar.py`. I guess the implementation is up to you

#### Solution 1 : The baseclass

Your architecture would be as follows :

```
module
|- __init__.py
|- foo.py
|- bar.py
|- mybase.py
```

And then, you would have your file `mybase.py` such as...

```py
class MyFooBase:
    pass

class MyBarBase:
    pass
```

Then, in your files `foo.py` and `bar.py`, you'd have the following file (I will only show one as it's obvious what the other would look like)...

```py
from .mybase import MyFooBase, MyBarBase

class Bar(MyBarBase):
  def __init__(self):
    self.number = 2

  def __mul__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, MyFooBase): raise ValueError('')
    return other.value * self.number
```

#### Solution 2 : Use something else than the type.

(See in comment)

Comment: For answering your implementation question: The problem with my implementation is the following: I have two objects Foo and Bar. They both contain lumpy arrays that are multiplied with one another. But the one from Bar is dynamically calculated dependent on other properties of Foo. That's the main problem.

Comment: @H.Müller Can you have only one class ? Or do you already have 2 classes implemented ?

Comment: I'm depending on both classes. Please trust me that it makes sense in my case.  It's a physical simulation.

Comment: @H.Müller And does the solution I have given solve your issue ? :)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I'd like to observe another day if there are other ideas – I'll upvote the answers then and mark my favorite. But maybe someone comes up with an even smarter idea. Hope, that's alright.

Comment: @H.Müller That is perfectly alright, I was wondering if the solution I proposed worked for you :)

Comment: @H.Müller However, if the other solution suits you, notice that he regrouped everything in one file, so, if you can group everything in one file, you won't have circular imports anymore :)

Comment: Technically it would work, but `__rmul__` is a rather simpler solution to my specific problem. Thanks anyway – the learned alternatives are useful because they show solutions I couldn't think of.